# Integration of Kuka KR16 with KRC2 controller

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey

Recently I have started working with ROS and RSI (so I am new in this) to control a Kuka KR16-2 robot with KRC2 controller. We just installed the KSS 5.6 and RSI 2.3. I have looked on the ROS support and I found the Kuka Experimental which integrate the robot KR16, but the files for the rsi_hw_interface (https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/tree/indigo-devel/kuka_rsi_hw_interface) are for the KRC4 controller.

I understood that for KRC4 is using the RSIVisual which (of-course) are not compatible with KRC2  (e.g. in KRC2 the folder C:\KRC\ROBOTER\Config\User\Common  does not exist; RSI_CREATE is not a valid command; etc.) and that I need to convert the files from KRC4 back to KRC2. However, sine I am a baby in this I do not know from where to start and where to stop. Is there someone still working with KRC2 controller and ROS? Can you share with me the files for KRC2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249679/integration-of-kuka-kr16-with-krc2-controller/) by [ccopot](https://answers.ros.org/users/28732/ccopot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-09**:
@ccopot: please don't post answers unless you are actually answering your own question. On ROS Answers things are a little different from a regular forum: instead of a chronological list of posts, it's a 1-to-1 question-answer system. Comments may be used for discussion / short remarks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a PR against kuka_experimental that adds support for KRC2. It works for me, but as far as i know it has not been tested by anyone else. Would be great if you can test this and see if it works.

Some warnings:
Using RSI the robot can move at full speed in teach mode.
Set the HOME and upper\lower bound variables to something suitable for your setup. They are in the **configuration fold** of **ros_rsi.src**

PR is at https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/pull/74

---

Originally posted by [ivareri](https://answers.ros.org/users/2134/ivareri/) with karma: 16 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0